# How do I import the pybind module I incorporated into my python module?

Tags: python, module, python-module, pybind11

I have created a python module that has the following structure (loosely based on [this example](https://github.com/pybind/python_example)):

```
module_name
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── module_name
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── submodule_name
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── submodule_name.py
├── setup.py
└── src
    └── sq.cpp
```

I can run `setup.py` and install this module without a problem. I can also import the pure python modules:

```
import module_name
import module_name.submodule_name
```

For `sq.cpp` I have the following in `setup.py`

```
from pybind11 import get_cmake_dir
from pybind11.setup_helpers import Pybind11Extension, build_ext


ext_modules = [
    Pybind11Extension("sq",
    ["src/sq.cpp"],),
]
```

`sq.cpp` defines the pybind module as

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(sq, m)
{
    m.doc() = "a function";
    m.def("sq", &sq, "a function");
}
```

At this point I'm confused about how to load the module in `sq.cpp`. I have tried `import sq`, `import module_name.sq`, `import sq.sq` but all result in a `ModuleNotFoundError`. What am I missing? How am I supposed to import the pybind module? Do I have the structure wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your build should fail as the names of the module and function are the same. (Look at `sq.cpp`)
When you define a module with `PYBIND11_MODULE(sq, m)`, the `sq` becomes a local variable and `&sq` will reffer to another object, but not to the `sq` function. So you can rename the name of the function to keep the module name as `sq`.

```cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

void _sq() {}

PYBIND11_MODULE(sq, m) {

    m.doc() = "a function";
    m.def("sq", &_sq, "a function");
}
```

##### Compare the following `setup.py` with yours

```cpp
import sys

from pybind11 import get_cmake_dir
from pybind11.setup_helpers import Pybind11Extension, build_ext
from setuptools import setup

__version__ = "0.0.1"

ext_modules = [
    Pybind11Extension("sq",
                      ["src/sq.cpp"],
                      define_macros=[('VERSION_INFO', __version__)],
                      ),
]

setup(
    name="sq",
    version=__version__,
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
    cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext},
    zip_safe=False,
    python_requires=">=3.6",
)
```

##### Install the module

Redirect to the parent directory of the `sq` module directory and execute the following command.

```
python3 -m pip install ./sq
```

##### Import the module

```py
import sq

sq.sq()
```

##### *Edit notes*

> I'm a bit confused because I already have a `setup` section with `name="module_name"`. How do I embed the `sq` module inside the whole `module_name` module?

You should change the module name by changing

- `Pybind11Extension("sq", ...)` to `Pybind11Extension("module_name", ...)`
- `setup(name="sq", ...)` to `setup(name="module_name", ...)`
- `PYBIND11_MODULE(sq, m)` to `PYBIND11_MODULE(module_name, m)`

After reinstalling the module with the command above, you can use the `sq` function in these ways.

```py
import module_name
from module_name import sq

module_name.sq()
sq()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm a bit confused because I already have a `setup` section with `name="module_name"`. How do I embed the `sq` module inside the whole `module_name` module?

Comment: Please read the *Edit notes* section I have added to my answer.

Comment: Turns out I can have the same module and function name. The problem was I was missing `ext_modules=ext_modules` in `setup()`. Also, I didn't want to change the pybind11 module to `module_name` -- I already have other python scripts inside `module_name`. I'll go ahead and accept your answer as it put me on the right path and my original question description was not great.